# "Mavenize" a Google project

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, maven-2, maven

I followed the StockWatcher GWT tutorial with success and made the integration with GAE datastore using JDO based persistence.

Now I wanted to introduce Objectify, a third party framework for persistence.

If I correctly understand, Google uses ant to manage project's lifecycle.

Some years ago, I was using Maven2, it was pretty handy to manage having always the latest versions of all your libraries.

How can I add Maven to my project (without creating it from scratch, obviously)?

Comment: Hm, are you asking about mavenizing without creating `pom.xml` from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the [Maven GAE plugin](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/index.html) and [gae-maven-goodies](http://code.google.com/p/gae-maven-goodies/) projects.

> The **maven-gae-plugin** provides support for Google App Engine projects.
>   Basically, it attempts to cover all the basic operations provided by
>   Google App Engine SDK, such as running project locally, deploying it
>   to Google's cloud, retrieving production logs etc.

Other resources:

[Mavenize an app engine project #1](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Mavenize-an-App-Engine-project-1-27001)
[Mavenize an app engine project #2](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Mavenize-an-App-Engine-project-2-29001)
[Mavenize an app engine project #3](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Mavenize-an-App-Engine-project-3-33001)

Answer (score 1):

there's also the [maven gwt plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/eclipse/google_plugin.html):